# hide everything on site

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to hide everything on site using jquery before it starts to be rendered ? I check query string and if something is as I expected I do postback and then want to render correct site content.

Comment: What do you mean by hide? Hide the stuff from plain sight? Or do you want to prevent the elements from being on the page (/ in the DOM) completely?

Comment: What happens if they turn off Javascript? This doesn't sound like a good plan

Comment: IMHO, If your only trying to improve aesthetics/UX then using JavaScript to hide the page isn't a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be better to just hide the body by default then do your postback and after that append a class with a style of 'display:block;' - otherwise as javascript isn't loaded straight away, you may get a flash where it loads and then hides.

Answer (score 1):

In the head you could do the following...

```
<head>
...

<script>$(function() { $(document.body).show(); });</script>

...
</>
```

In the body you can have the following...

```
<body>
   <script>document.body.style.display = 'none';</script>


   ...

</body>
```

Using this approach will not produce a flash on the page...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$('body').hide()`, change body tag content with `$('body').hide(content)` and then use `$('body').show()`.

Comment: Think you meant `html` instead of `hide` on the second one.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is the following:

- Start the page without any content but an AJAX loader.
- Check the query string and let it return either the html or an object which states query string is invalid
- if valid load html in dom
- if invalid notify user

This way prevents users to see the content even if query string is invalid because they have disabled javascript.

Also just hiding stuff is bad, because users can just manipulate the DOM to show the elements.

Comment: but in this case without javascript enable page cant be viewed.

Comment: @gruber: That's correct. However the answer you checked as answer has the exact same issue :P I would add a notification on the main page which states that javascript must be enabled. And hide this notification using javascript (so that users who have js enabled don't see it). To do hide it using javascript in the head tag of the document so users won't see the notification when do don't need to